# .NET Core - DllImport BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core

I created project which is referencing x86 dll. But when I call the imported function it throws exception:

> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program
>   with an incorrect format.

Program.cs:

```
[DllImport("lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern int func(int a, int ab, int c, int d, int e);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    func(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="lib.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.0.0-preview2-25407-01" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>`
```

It doesn't work if it targets netcoreapp2.0, but when I change the target framework to "net45" it works (I need netcoreapp because it's multiplatform)

Does anyone know where there could be a problem?

Comment: Is it possible - just possible - that your lib.dll was compiled for .NET 4.5 and not .NET Core?

Comment: It is native x86 dll written in C, compiled by MSVC, so I don't think so.

Comment: Have you ensured that both are compiled for x86 then?  Because it's either that or your dll isn't a dll.

Comment: I used "dumpbin /headers lib.dll" for analyzing dll, it shows "14C machine (x86)", and in csproj I set "RuntimeIdentifier" to win-x86, so I think it is both x86, but how can I verify that the .Net Core app really running on x86?

Comment: Is not dll windows concept? How native dll can work with .NET Core which is supposed to be cross platform?

Comment: have a look here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13501/Platform-Independent-Coding-DLLs-and-SOs

Comment: it is standard dll generated by MSVC in Windows and it works in .Net Framework 4.5. It will be crossplatform because i will use dll in windows and .so lib in linux. On linux side DllImport works